# GCC:skipping incompatible /home/Linux/lib/libtest.a when searching for -ltest

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I am compiling code on my Linux arch64 ARM machine with gcc version 4.8,
We are hitting below warning messages while linking

Warning:-

`skipping incompatible /home/Linux/lib/libtest.a when searching for -ltest`

I know that ARM cpu only support 32 bit. Is it because of some compatability issue with the library?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because of some compatability issue with the library?

Yes. A 64-bit linkage, for example, will skip 32-bit libraries that would otherwise be
selected, and vice versa, and this warning will be issued. But as long as
the linker *does* find compatible versions of all the libraries that it
requires, you do not have a problem. If the linker cannot find a compatible
library that it requires, it will give an *error* and the linkage will fail.
Such warnings are routine in environments where libraries of diverse architectures
co-exist in the linker's search paths.

Comment: Thanks. I have one doubt. While i was running build on x86_64 machine i did not see any such issue. But in ARM machine with aarch 64, while compiling the code first error i have is '-m32 unrecognized' option for gcc. And i came to know that on arch64 machine -m32 option is not supported so,i removed and compilation went fine. the way of building is 64bit or 32 bit in my case? How to find whether a library is build with 64/32 bit? Is there a way to resolve the issue?

Comment: @ Mike, Can you please respond?